# How to correctly install Face_recognition?

Tags: python

I wanted to work on a project involving face recognition, but when I tried to install face_recognition library, it gave me this output-

```
Collecting face_recognition
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/95/f6c9330f54ab07bfa032bf3715c12455a381083125d8880c43cbe76bb3d0/face_recognition-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting dlib>=19.7 (from face_recognition)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/92/05c3b98636661cb80d190a5a777dd94effcc14c0f6893222e5ca81e74fbc/dlib-19.19.0.tar.gz
Collecting face-recognition-models>=0.3.0 (from face_recognition)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/3b/4fd8c534f6c0d1b80ce0973d01331525538045084c73c153ee6df20224cf/face_recognition_models-0.3.0.tar.gz
Collecting Click>=6.0 (from face_recognition)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/37/45185cb5abbc30d7257104c434fe0b07e5a195a6847506c074527aa599ec/Click-7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy (from face_recognition)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/ef/9f2eeb4ff0c733ad9149f17266e388c308e171fdb8c2415dbb472e2bbc0f/numpy-1.16.6-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting Pillow (from face_recognition)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/b6/8960697526a79bd1cb4520293078be3a10d725f23f20abbee298ebdeaabd/Pillow-6.2.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: dlib, face-recognition-models, Click, numpy, Pillow, face-recognition
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python27\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\adity\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-rosjjw\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\adity\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-rosjjw\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'c:\users\adity\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-jqvmxp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: c:\users\adity\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-rosjjw\dlib\
    Complete output (40 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\adity\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-rosjjw\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\adity\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-rosjjw\dlib\setup.py", line 129, in run
        cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
      File "c:\users\adity\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-rosjjw\dlib\setup.py", line 125, in get_cmake_version
        "\n*******************************************************************\n")
    RuntimeError:
    *******************************************************************
     CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib
    *******************************************************************

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python27\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\adity\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-rosjjw\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\adity\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-rosjjw\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'c:\users\adity\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-jqvmxp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

How can I fix this? In Windows 10?
*I guess I have to install Cmake and Dlib, but it's giving the same error
(python 3.6.8)

Comment: https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/175#issue-257710508

Comment: first of all, are u installing it from a virtual enviroment?

Comment: No. And, I don't want it to be installed in a virtenv

Answer (score 0):

```
 RuntimeError:
    *******************************************************************
     CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib
    *******************************************************************
```

I ran into the same problem recently, I resolved it downloading CMAKE.

[Here is the link to download it for each OS](https://cmake.org/download/)